# How to move from a AbilitySlice to a Ability in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am trying to move from an AbilitySlice to an Ability. I tried the below code,
But was it not working as expected.

```
Operation systemOperation = new Intent.OperationBuilder()
                        .withBundleName(getBundleName())
                        .withAbilityName(MainAbility.class.getSimpleName())
                        .build();
                intent.setOperation(systemOperation);
                startAbility(intent);
```

for moving from an AbilitySlice to Ability in Harmony OS?

Comment: Have you mentioned your Target Ability in Config.json @Sahana G R, reference usage : https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/BottomBar/blob/master/entry/src/main/java/com/example/bottombar/sample/slice/MainAbilitySlice.java

Answer (score 0):

Try to Delete `Simple` from `getSimpleName`. Like following:

```
Operation systemOperation = new Intent.OperationBuilder()
                        .withBundleName(getBundleName())
                        .withAbilityName(MainAbility.class.getName())
                        .build();
                intent.setOperation(systemOperation);
                startAbility(intent);
```

Comment: Error message: 
08-09 20:24:57.310 7136-7136/com.github.mzelzoghbi E 01100/AppExecFwk: ContextDeal::getAbilityShellDatasLocal failed, abilityInfos is empty
08-09 20:24:57.310 7136-7136/com.github.mzelzoghbi I 02D03/HiTraceC: [807f221e994be28, 0, 0] HiTraceBegin name:fetchAbilities flags:1.
08-09 20:24:57.319 7136-10149/com.github.mzelzoghbi E 01100/AbilityShell: DistributedManager::fetchAbilities sendRequest failed
08-09 20:24:57.319 7136-7136/com.github.mzelzoghbi E 01100/AppExecFwk: [807f221e994be28, 0, 0] ContextDeal::startAbility fetchAbilities failed

Comment: i tried the code mentioned above. not working

Comment: For details, you may refer the following development document :  [link1](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ability-ability-overview-0000000000029852)  [link2](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ability-intent-0000000000038799) [link 3](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ability-page-switching-0000000000037999), this might help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Not working as expected" generally is not a valid error description. I'd suspect the `AbilitySlice` might belong to `MainAbility` and the whole operation might therefore be pointless, as navigation from A to B could not happen. The example which @Gowtham provided has one small difference (which appears to consider the device on which to launch the `Intent` with Super Device):

```
 .withDeviceId("")
```

Have you ever tried to start anything else but `MainAbility`?

Comment: I am trying to start, an ability, in a different package, from the parent package.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have mentioned that the package name of your target ability is different than the package name of your ability slice in your reply to @Martin.
Then, you need to make sure the bundleName(or package name) specified in the Intent's Operation builder is having the target ability's package name and not the calling ability's/abilityslice's package name.

```
Operation systemOperation = new Intent.OperationBuilder()
                        .withBundleName("enter_package_name_of target_ability_here")
                        .withAbilityName(MainAbility.class.getName())
                        .build();
                intent.setOperation(systemOperation);
                startAbility(intent);
```